# in yii2, how to show/hide column dynamically

Tags: yii2

I am using gridview/Dynagrid widget,and having approximatly 60 columns in it. it looks bad to see all columns at a time. Is there any widget or way to show/hide columns dynamically??
thanks in advance!!
here is code
index.php

```
     echo DynaGrid::widget([
    'columns' => $gridColumns,//I have 60 columns in $gridcolumn, requirement is to show/hide column dynamically
    'storage'=>DynaGrid::TYPE_COOKIE,

    'gridOptions'=>[
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'filterModel'=>$searchModel,

    ],
     'options'=>['id'=>'dynagrid-1'] 
]);

    ?>
```

Comment: Please try by yourself to write some code and copy there.After we can help you.

Comment: you can get the answer from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968615/yii2-gridview-toggle-column

Answer (score 0):

first, you will download Yii2-DynamicForm

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform "*"
```

secend this two videos will help you
part 1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqFpTBr323Y
part 2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAg0LIrZDdk

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option: [DynaGrid](http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid)

Comment: I have already installed dynagrid.it working fine showing table but i cant understand how its code for show and hide column.. also doesnt found any demo related to this.. ...Thanks for answer

Comment: yes have seen this.. but it does not show hide column..the requirement is..ex see above demo page ..i just want to see name,color,author column at a time... In next execution i wanna to see name and color